# How to terminate a .exe program with electron?

Tags: electron, exe

Essentially what I'm trying to do is to run a program named app.exe with electron, and then terminate it.

I have been successful with running the app.exe program using the following code:

```
let child = require('child_process').execFile;
let executablePath = "dist/app.exe";

child(executablePath, function(err, data) {
    if(err){
       console.error(err);
       return;
    }
});
```

I would like to have something that does the opposite, something that terminates the program.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Node's [subprocess.kill()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal) for this purpose. In the following example, the subprocess is killed after one second.

```js
let child = require('child_process').execFile;
let executablePath = "dist/app.exe";

let sp = child(executablePath, function(err, data) {
    if(err){
       console.error(err);
       return;
    }
});

setTimeout(function() {
    sp.kill()
}, 1000)
```